# Python evaluating imported module class as 'type' when used as parameter

Tags: python

I have imported class from an external module explicitly. I can create objects of this type, but when used as a parameter i.e. Passing class type to method, the method evaluates the class as 'type'.

Using the namespace prefix is non-resolvable too. The method evaluates python base types fine i.e. passing int is evaluated as int...

test.py

```
import os
import sys
import math
import time
import traceback
import datetime
import argparse

from i_factory_type import IFactoryType
from example_factory_type import ExampleFactoryType
from factory import Factory

if __name__ == "__main__":

    obj = ExampleFactoryType()
    print(type(obj))
    print(isinstance(obj, IFactoryType))
    obj.make()
    factory = Factory()
    factory.register('123', ExampleFactoryType)
```

factory.py

```
'''
Polymorphic factory that creates IFactoryTypes with dispatching
'''

from i_factory_type import IFactoryType

'''
Implementation of factory
'''
class Factory:

    def Factory(self):

        self.registry = dict()

    def register(self, i_id, i_type):

        print(isinstance(i_type, IFactoryType))
        print(i_type.__class__)
        assert( isinstance(i_type, IFactoryType) )

        self.unregister_type(i_id)

        self.registry[i_id] = staticmethod(i_type)

    def unregister(self, i_id):

        if i_is in self.registry:
            del self.registry[i_id]

    def clear(self):

        self.registery.clear()

    def make_object(self, i_id, *i_args):

        ret = None

        if i_id in self.registry:
            ret = self.registry[i_id](i_args)

        return ret
```

example_factory_type.py

```
'''
Base type for factory create method
'''

from i_factory_type import IFactoryType

'''
Interface for factory creation
'''
class ExampleFactoryType(IFactoryType):

    @staticmethod
    def make(*i_args):

        print('factory make override')
```

i_factory_type.py

```
'''
Base type for factory create method
'''


'''
Interface for factory creation
'''
class IFactoryType:

    @staticmethod
    def make(*i_args):

        raise NotImplementedError('Must override factory type')
```

Output:

```
<class 'example_factory_type.ExampleFactoryType'>
True
factory make override
False
<class 'type'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    factory.register('123', ExampleFactoryType)
  File "F:\code\factory.py", line 20, in register
    assert( isinstance(i_type, IFactoryType) )
AssertionError
```

Comment: Fix your indent.

Comment: @Rahul The code isn't indented like this, its only on stack overflow

Comment: Then... post your actual code on [SO].

Comment: Also explain why you are expecting that assertion to be true. What actually are IFactoryType and ExampleFactoryType?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Alright have all the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assertion is wrong:

```
assert( isinstance(i_type, IFactoryType) )
```

You should instead say:

```
assert issubclass(i_type, IFactoryType)
```

An instance of `ExampleFactoryType` would be an instance of `IFactoryType`, but the class itself is not an instance of its base classes.

All python classes are instances of `type`. Even the type `type` is an instance of itself.

Maybe this helps you understand the difference between types and instances:

```
obj = ExampleFactoryType()
isinstance(obj, ExampleFactoryType) # True
isinstance(obj, IFactoryType) # True
isinstance(ExampleFactoryType, IFactoryType) # False
issubclass(ExampleFactoryType, IFactoryType) # True
isinstance(ExampleFactoryType, type) # True
isinstance(IFactoryType, type) # True
```

Comment: Spot on, makes sense. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

A class is not an instance of its superclass; `isinstance(ExampleFactoryType, IFactoryType)` will always be false. This would work for an *instance* of ExampleFactoryType (eg `obj`), but not for the class itself.

Comment: print(type(obj)) evaluates as <class 'example_factory_type.ExampleFactoryType'>. print(isinstance(obj, IFactoryType)) evaluates true

Comment: Yes, that's what I said - isinstance works for instances, not classes.